# Moving the build code from one location to server programatically (C#) using MSDeploy.exe

Tags: c#, msdeploy

I have a requirement  to use MSDeploy.exe and move the build code from local machine to server machine programatically (Dotnet c#).

I am not sure how to use the MSDeploye.exe and passing the arguments for the destination folders and source folders.

I am little aware that we have an xml file which can be used to pass parameters to the MSDeploy.exe but I am not sure how can I configure the same for my problem.

Thnx in advance.

Sidharth Gupta

Comment: Please consult the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[How to use MS deploy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104(v=vs.110).aspx)

The above link has how to use the deployment tool. With command line options etc

such as

`ProjectName.deploy.cmd /t "-skip:objectName= filePath,absolutePath=\\ApplicationFolder\\web\.config$"`

[Web deploy command link reference](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=182928)

has some more specifics